# toolkit MediaElement show image when playing mp3 in .net maui app

Tags: xamarin, audio, xamarin.ios, maui, mediaelement

I'm using a MediaElement Control to play an mp3 in our .net maui app. Only problem that when running on iOS it just show black in the playback control or just shows the QuickTime like the following:

[image]

Just wondering how we put our own image in the mediaElement while the mp3 plays? Like an album image or whatever?

Comment: I would suggest a hack by adding Image over Media element, and controls of MediaElement over Image with implemented event handlers to play/pause/skip.